# create table from select then alter table by adding an auto increment column in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, auto-increment

as briefly explained in subject, I need to create a table by selecting existing value.
The thing I would like to achieve is to have another column with auto incremented value.

This is what I already tried:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tb (    
    `row_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `stm_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    descr varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (row_id)
);
```

Then after with a select:

```
INSERT INTO temp_tb (
  select stm_id,descr from tb_export
)
```

I was expecting to have the row_id column prefilled at insert time, but I just got sql syntax error telling me that column count doesn't match value count.

Do you know if this is possible to achieve ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should provide the names of the columns you are inserting into your temp_tb:

```
INSERT INTO temp_tb (stm_id, descr) (
  select stm_id,descr from tb_export
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, the syntax error has to do with your insert syntax.  You have a temp_tb that has 3 fields, all not null.  You are inserting 2 fields into that table with your insert statement.  The MySQL ref lists the syntax for insert using select as:

INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
  FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;